# Opening Excel using Jexcel

Tags: java, jframe, jexcelapi

Hi Guys I am trying to display An excel sheet page in JFrame using this code

```
 JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    Container cp = frame.getContentPane();
    cp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
     File workbookFile = new File("C:\\Workbook.xls");         

    //Opening the specified file in the JWorkbook component
    JWorkbook jWorkbook = new JWorkbook(workbookFile); 
    cp.add(jWorkbook);
```

But I am getting the Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jniwrapper/win32/automation/OleContainer
at excel.open.ExcelOpen.main(ExcelOpen.java:29)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jniwrapper.win32.automation.OleContainer
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
... 1 more
Java Result: 1
```

I Have the following Jar in My ClassPath: jexcel-1.5.23878.jar. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to add [ComfyJ](http://www.teamdev.com/comfyj/) to your classpath as well and it will get beyond this error.

Answer (score 1):

You should add comfyj-x.x.jar to the classpath as well.